# C programming, manipulating functions' arguments and return

Tags: c, function, return, arguments, pass-by-value

All

Should not the output be -24 ?
I'm getting -4 as a result and can not get the reason .

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int g (int x, int y) {
   x = x + y;
   int z = 2 * x - y;
   return z;
   }


int main()
{
    printf("Hello World%d\n", g(3, -10));

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: No, -4 is correct

Comment: The reason is elementary school math. `2 * (3 + -10) - (-10) = ?`

Comment: The return is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the function as

```
g(3, -10)
```

That means inside the function, the variable `x` starts out with the value `3` and `y` with the value `-10`.

Now if we do the arithmetic on "paper" we first have

```
x = x + y;
```

which is the same as

```
x = 3 + -10;
```

which is the same as

```
x = -7;
```

Then you have

```
int z = 2 * x - y;
```

which is the same as

```
int z = 2 * -7 - -10;
```

which is the same as

```
int z = -14 + 10;
```

which is the same as

```
int z = -4;
```

And then you return the value of `z` which has the value `-4`.

It's all elementary basic math as taught in most elementary schools.